# set relativenumbers colors in VIM

Tags: vim, vi, line-numbers

I use `set relativenumber` in VIM, and cannot imagine my life without it.

What bothers me is that the numbers above and below 0 look the same. If I see the number 9, I don't know if I have to 9j or 9k to jump there at first glance (and often go in the wrong direction)

Is it possible to have the "negative" numbers a different color from the positive numbers, so I can tell them apart faster?

Thanks!

Comment: IMHO it's impossible. You can highlight the current line to make it more clearly visible (`:h hl-CursorLine`, `h: hl-CursorLineNr`)

Comment: @Ves This seems to be as close as we may get. Would you mind turning your comment into a real answer? Especially showing the `set cursorline`/`highlight CursorLineNr ...` combination?

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if there is a way highlight it without much work. What I do have in my `vimrc` is

1) highlight the current line

2) set number(nu) as well along with relative number(rnu) which makes the current line number looks different. See the number 26, for example

[image]